# Maven and AppServer dependency management best practice

Tags: java, maven-2

I am developing a web-app and use maven for dependency management (duh). Some of the needed jars are already available in the server lib folder, but do not match the "maven naming scheme", ie missing the version suffix.

I would like to use them for development and deployment, but..
1. i cant point maven to them because maven seem to need a version suffix. I cant omit it in the pom. 
2. If i define the dependency outside maven then maven is obviously unable to build. 
3. Renaming the files inside the server distribution sounds like a kludge.

What would Brian Boitano do? I mean, there sure is an elegant solution that im not aware of, or at least a good argument for one of the three solutions above.

Thank you

PS. i am using jboss 5.1 and maven 2.2.1 atm, but its subject to change

Comment: i guess i should have named the question "how to avoid redundant jar deployment with maven". so i've got 2 "best practices" so far - "dont try to be smart" from c0mrade and "use system scope for local libs" from dimitrisli. system scope is supposed to be sorta deprecated though. i wonder if the deprecation is still valid regarding relative path with environment vars like JBOSS_HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide those jars as a dependency with a `system` scope if you want explicitly to identify where they live. For more info have a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

Comment: thanks, i already figured out how to point mvn to local jars but there is still the version suffix issue...got an idea for that one too?

Comment: what do you mean by suffix issue? If you provide <scope>system</scope> and <systemPath>fullPathFileWithoutVersionSuffix.jar</systemPath> in your dependency then you should be fine.

Comment: my bad, didnt point maven explicitly to the jar but to the lib folder. works now :) and with ${env.JBOSS_HOME} the system scope aint that bad

Answer (score 0):

IF those are not proprietary libs you are using, I'd recommend you use official versions of those from maven repository.

If they are proprietary you can manually install jar to your local repository using maven(you can use your version, suffixes, group names, artifactid etc) and then use them in your pom.

Comment: thank you. seems like your solution is to ignore the fact that the jar is there already and just follow the regular procedure. Thats an option i didnt mention but: 1. i would like to avoid redundant deployments for common jars and 2. why are you preferring repo jars to the ones provided by the server distribution?

Comment: @kostja 1. Because that is how maven works, if you don't like it don't use it. You must have artifactId, groupId etc. 2. They are basically the same, but if you want to keep of the track of the latest versions its easier that maven does that for you, than that you care about that.

Comment: im afraid the choice of tools for a project is not always about personal preferences, at least not my personal preferences :) btw i really like maven, you kinda have to after having used ant. im just rather new to it. how would you share a jar between webapps "the mvn way" without duplicating it?

Comment: @kostja maven unlike ant is not just build tool, its much more. "Convention over configuration" means do as I want(maven) and you're gonna have good time, that is at least my understanding, I might be wrong however.